# Remove S3 object by upload date using .NET API

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3

Is there an option using [AWS .NET AP](http://aws.amazon.com/en/sdkfornet/)I to delete objects from a bucket by a start and end date in which they were uploaded/created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can configure your object to delete after no of days to upload date. For that you need to apply Amazon S3 Lifecycle. Here you can mention Object Expiration details. You can give date on which object should delete as well as Number of days after the creation (upload) on amazon s3.

http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--set-object-expiration-on-amazon-s3-objects-put-get-delete-bucket-lifecycle.html